# Sequelize: Able to create even foreignKey is deleted (paranoid type)

Tags: node.js, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

### Issue Description

I created 2 table, `user` and `role`. One of the field in `user` is `roleId`, which pointed to `role` table.
Both tables `paranoid` equal to `true`.
If `role.id` 2 is [paranoid] deleted (`deletedAt` is has value), I still able to insert `roleId: 2` in `user` table.
[UPDATE]: even `models.update` can update `roleId: 2` too

#### Files

UserModel.js

```
class User extends Model {}

User.init({
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
  tableName: 'user',
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true
})

export default User
```

RoleModel.js

```
class Role extends Model {}

Role.init({
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
}, {
  sequelize,
  tableName: 'role',
  timestamps: true,
  paranoid: true
})

export default Role
```

index.js

```
import RoleModel from './RoleModel'
import UserModel from './UserModel'

RoleModel.hasOne(UserModel, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: 'roleId',
    fieldName: 'id',
    allowNull: true
  }
})
UserModel.belongsTo(RoleModel, {
  as: 'role'
})

export {
  RoleModel,
  UserModel
}
```

#### Environment

- Sequelize version: 6.3.5
- Node.js version: v12.18.0
- Operating System: MacOS
- dialects: mysql

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can indicate a soft-deleted record id because this record still exists in DB and you can get a user with this role if you indicate `paranoid: false` while getting a user along with a role:

```js
const user = User.findById(userId, {
  paranoid: false,
  include: [Role]
}
```